# Network Request Fail in fetch React Native

Tags: react-native

Network request fails with fetch to `http://localhost:3000/api/register`

```html
    import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import axios from "axios";

const RegisterScreen = () => {

    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    const handleRegister = async () => {
        console.log('Handling registration...');
        try{
        console.log('Handling registration...');
        const response =await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/register")
        }
        catch(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
        
        console.log('Handling response data...');
      };
      
    
      
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={{color:"#00ffff", fontSize:25, marginBottom:10}}>Register</Text>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="UserName"
                value={username}    
                onChangeText={setUsername}
            />
            <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="Email"
                value={email}
                onChangeText={setEmail}
            />
            <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="Password"
                value={password}
                onChangeText={setPassword}
                secureTextEntry

            />
            <Button title="Register" onPress={handleRegister}/>
        </View>
    )


}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        backgroundColor: "#000000",
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center"
    },
    input: {
        backgroundColor: "#ffd700",
        width: '80%',
        borderWidth: 1,
        padding: 10,
        marginBottom: 10,

    }

})

export default RegisterScreen;**strong text**
```